# integrate 1 way call in my application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outbound

I am trying to implement a call system in my application, where I can provide a button to the user "Call Me", and on pressing that button, the user receives a recorded message which provides the user some 2 digit code, and when user enters that 2 digit code into my application, my application authenticates him and register's him, but I am not sure what I should look for, for achiving this type of functionality. Please note that I am working on ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

> but I am not sure what I should look for, for achiving this type of functionality

You should be looking into purchasing an SMS gateway API. Once you purchase such service you will be able to send SMS messages to mobile phones from your application using the provided API.